# RealmSwift - how can I query a distinct array of objects

Tags: swift, realm

I have the following (simplified) model

```
class Taxonomy: Object {
   var id: ObjectId // Primary Key
   var parent: Taxonomy?
   var name: String
   var isSelected: Bool 

   var children = List<Taxonomy>()

   var assets = List<Asset>()


}

class Asset: Object {
   var id: String // Primary Key
   var name: String

   let taxonomies = LinkingObjects(fromType: Taxonomy.self, property: "assets")

}
```

The taxonomy can be an infinite hierarchy with each item containing zero or more children.  A leaf would have no children. Assets can be classified as one or more 'leaf' taxonomies.

For example Animals->Birds->"White-faced Pigeon"

There could be multiple assets, let's say images ( but could be documents, recording, etc.) that have this classification with the references stored in Taxonomy.assets array.

If the user selected 'Birds' in the hierarchy then I want to retrieve a distinct list of all the assets from the SELECTED taxonomies and all their children's assets and the children's children etc.

In general only 'leaf' taxonomy items will contain assets - but not necessarily so since some assets may for example be as yet unclassified birds and simply associated with a higher level group until further refinement is done.

For example:

```
let selectedTaxonomies = realm.objects(Taxonomy.self).filter("isSelected = true")

let children = selectedTaxonomies.flatMap({$0.children})

let childrensChildren = children({$0.children})

etc... (how to traverse a hierarchy of arbitrary depth)

let assets = allSelectedTaxonomies.flatMap({$0.assets}).distinct(by: "id")
```

Is there any way to do this in some efficient way.

EDIT:

This seems to work but not sure it is very efficient

```
extension Taxonomy {
   var allChildren: [Taxonomy] {
        return Array(children)+Array(children.flatMap({$0.allChildren}))
    }
}
```

and then

```
let selectedTaxonomies = realm.objects(Taxonomy.self).filter("isSelected == true")
            
let allChildren = selectedTaxonomies.flatMap({$0.allChildren})
           
let allTaxonomies = Array(selectedTaxonomies) + Array(allChildren)
            
assets = assets.filter("ANY taxonomies IN %@", allTaxonomies)
```

Example

Here the user could select images and drag and drop them onto one or more of the classifications on the left. So the same item could appear in more than one place.  For example one of the eagle images might also appear in another hierarchy called Best Of -> Birds for example.  Right now I am doing a super expensive fetch of the selected taxonomy hierarchy and am trying to establish if there is a way to build a Realm query maybe using Predicates that would be faster/more efficient.

[image]

Comment: There are a few coding issues that need clarifying. 1) What is `Taxonomies.self` as that object is not in included in the question. 2) `flatMap({$0.allChildren}` disconnects those objects from Realm so they are no longer live updating. Perhaps using one of the aggregate expressions like `distinctUnionOfObjects` would be better. 3) Objects that have a child property of that same object is often a design issue - what's the use case? 4) What makes an object *distinct* - what's the comparison to separates it from other objects?

Comment: Oh, and the question title is *how can I query a distinct array of objects* - is that actually what you're asking? Arrays do not guarantee distinct-ness (a Set does) and it seems you're querying Realm, not an array. Or maybe you are? Can you clarify what you're actually attempting to do? Maybe include 'here's what I have, and here's what I want' in the question?

Comment: Sorry Taxonomies.self should have been Taxonomy.self.

Comment: @Jay - just updated with a bit of an explanation re the hierarchical nature of taxonomies.  If possible querying Realm would likely be more efficient but it's not clear whether that will be possible.  Perhaps a redesign of the model may be a better option - open to any suggestions.

Comment: Oh and Asset.id are distinct (didn't include the primary keys. And yes 'allChildren' - probably should be called 'allDescendants' - breaks from Realm but gets all descendants.  I don't know of a way to achieve the same with a realm query.

Comment: It's still really unclear and you may be overcomplicating it trying to have objects that are both parent's and children of the same object type. For example, the question states *If the user selected 'Birds' in the hierarchy* - where would they select Birds and what make one object a bird and not another? How would you query for birds if there is no property to store the word 'bird' in. A lot more clarification will be needed for us to understand what you're trying to do and where the trouble it. Also, review my above comment as you have additional coding issues to resolve as well.

Comment: @Jay - hierarchies are quite common - like Finders folders on macOS - so it's a common design pattern.  Folders within folders within folders...  One folder called Birds contains another folder called Pigeons and another called Eagles.  And unclassified image of a bird needs to show up in the Birds folder whereas classified images of eagles show up in the Eagles folder.  SwiftUI List will build the folder structure from the data hierarchy.

Comment: lol. I *know* what a hierarchy is - i've been coding for 45 years! I wasn't asking about the hierarchy - I was asking about what makes one object different from another. How that's determined is what will make your query work. As is, there's nothing that makes an object a Bird, or a Car or a Pizza. So I pose this question; suppose a user wants a list of all Birds in your database, and then wants a separate list of all Birds that are Eagles (assuming there are different types of Eagles in the database). How would that query look?

Comment: Ah an object is a bird if it is classified as a Bird or any subclassification of Bird.  Each Taxonomy object has a Taxonomy.assets property containing all items classified as that classification - so to get all birds you have to get all assets from the Birds taxonomy object plus all the assets from each of its descendant objects.  Each asset has a taxonomies property containing the LinkingObjects. How to query all birds efficiently is the subject of this question. Actually how to get all assets from the selected classifications is more broadly the question.

Comment: Just thinking out load here but I am beginning to suspect the overall design is an issue. In a file system there are three distinct objects; the root, the folder and the document / application etc. In Taxonomy there are (loosely corresponding) Animals, Birds and Anseriformes / Galliformes / Podicepeiformes etc. So it appears trying to cast everything into the same object type is going to be problematic with getting back data in queries. I will think through it more but having every object be the same type of generic object is going to be challenging.